# Can I decrypt password in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, encryption, passwords

I have a SQL Server database and an ASP.NET MVC project. I changed register model in project. After this time my users can register, but not log in. I see password encrypt error. How I can decrypted password?

```
public static string CreateHash(string password)
{
    // Generate a random salt
    var csprng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    var salt = new byte[SaltByteSize];
    csprng.GetBytes(salt);
    var hash = Pbkdf2(password, salt, Pbkdf2Iterations, HashByteSize);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
}
```

and

```
private static byte[] Pbkdf2(string password, byte[] salt, int iterations, int outputBytes)
{
    var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt) { IterationCount = iterations };
    return pbkdf2.GetBytes(outputBytes);
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be able to decrypt the password because it shouldn't be encrypted, it should be *hashed*.  And the whole point of hashing a password is to make it impossible to retrieve the original.  What's the *actual error* that you're getting and what are you actually trying to do?  The code you're showing has a syntax error which the compiler is surely pointing out to you.

Comment: Don't forget to add a little salt to the hash.

Comment: As @David said, you cannot decrypt a hashed password. To authenticate your registered users, you can consider encrypting and hashing the user entered password and compare that hash against the password hash in DB for that user.